# Encouraging existing Ubuntu teams to use SE

Tags: discussion

This isn't really a question but I guess I should bring it up now rather than later. In an effort to help spread the word I have asked some existing Ubuntu teams to start participating.

I started with the kernel team because in the past they have had concerns about tons of junk information about kernel support out there on the internet, so I've asked them to start participating in an effort to ensure users are getting the proper support.

Like many of us who started participating on SE we're going to need help getting existing teams used to the SE-way of going things, I just thought I'd announce this on meta because I plan and hope to involve as many existing teams in the project on here as we can muster.

Answer (score 3):

why is there going to be yet another place to contact a team?  We have Answers on launchpad, the corresponding freenode channel and the corresponding mailing list seems like a lot of places to have conversations in regards to contributing or suggesting changes.

Will this also become diluted by becoming a place to post bugs as well?  Then we will have bugs.launchpad.net as well?

Look the forums have a problem we all know that, but I think spreading the community thin will  be bad for the community as a whole

Comment: It isn't another place to contact a team, it's just another medium. Let's say we have the top 20 questions for kernel support in SE, if every single top answer is a link to the specific wiki page the kernel team maintains then that's a win.

And no, of course this won't be a place to report bugs because we'll all be making sure it doesn't turn into that.

I don't think it spreads us thin at all, in my opinion this forces all to focus on stepping up our support game; look at stackoverflow's success vs. Launchpad Answers.

Comment: On a related note and another example. Here is the kernel team's FAQ page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ

Ideally, assuming this site was out of beta and mature; instead of a team having to maintain a FAQ page, you could just point to the tag for that team and sort by popularity or whatever and you'd have a self maintained FAQ based on real time feedback; assuming the team in that area was active in the SE it would work out great.

Answer (score 3):

I also think we should start reaching out to Ubuntu LoCos for support and participation on the site. Their knowledge and love for the platform could bring a lot of great answers and atmosphere to the site.